# SSL Certificate for web app

Tags: ssl, web-applications, https, certificate, cherrypy

I have a WordPress + WooCommerce online store which is hosted on a managed hosting. I just bought non-wildcard SSL Certificate for that online store.

I am also developing a CherryPy Python Web App which must must use HTTPS for communication with WooCommerce API in order to update the inventory of the online store.

Here is where I am confused:

If my CherryPy Web App is deployed on Virtual Private Server (not where my online store is hosted) which SSL certificate can/should I use :

- The one that I just bought
- I should use Self-Signed SSL certificate
- Deploy the app where my website + certificate are
- Deploy my website on the VPS server where my Web App is

Maybe I am not in the right direction at all ?

Thank you,

Lisbeth

Answer (score 2):

The SSL certificate for your online store will only work for that domain. If you want to set up a separate web app to update that store over https then you will need to purchase another certificate for that new domain.

Self-signed certificates should really only ever be used locally during development. They are used as a workaround to allow for https without the need to officially verify identity (and pay for a certificate) given that everything is running locally.